# ios objective C screenshot sublayer not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm building an app where i want to take a snapshot from the camera and show it in a UIImageView. I'm able to take the snapshot but the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is not visible in the screenshot. Does anyone know how to do that?
Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController
CGRect imgRect;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //Capture Session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

    //Add device
    AVCaptureDevice *device =
    [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //Input
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];

    if (!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Input");
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    //Output
    output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];
    output.videoSettings = @{ (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) };

    //Preview
    previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    CGFloat x = self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5 - 128;
    imgRect = CGRectMake(x, 64, 256, 256);
    previewLayer.frame = imgRect;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    //Start capture session
    [session startRunning];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)TakeSnapshot:(id)sender {
    self.imgResult.image = self.pb_takeSnapshot;
}

- (UIImage *)pb_takeSnapshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
@end
```

a bit of help is very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Gilbert Avezaat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AVCaptureStillImageOutput to get image from the camera connection,

Here is how you could do it,

```
    AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    stillImageOutput.outputSettings = @{
                                        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG,
                                        (__bridge id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
                                        };
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:connection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }];
```

Comment: i have tried you're example and it actually shows a image. But the image is washed out see http://www.firstpolygon.com/images/example01.jpg for the output. and it is also rotated?

Comment: @MMWizard, Ok there could be some settings mismatch. I have edited above answer. You could also generate image directly from CMSampleBufferRef.

Comment: Sorry but i have found something. if i change: kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast to kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst. then the colors look okay. Now i only need to rotate the image. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

first check for  Image is return or not . if return then ...

```
- (IBAction)TakeSnapshot:(id)sender {

self.imgResult.image = self.pb_takeSnapshot;

[self.view bringSubviewToFrunt:self.imgResult];

}
```

hope it help you .

Comment: Hi Garry, It is still the same. It doesn't show the camera preview in the screenshot. What i actually need is a snapshot from the camera preview in the previewlayer.

Comment: this method pb_takeSnapshot  retum a image or not .

Comment: well it returns a image. but does not include the camera preview layer. Or is it possible to grab a frame from that layer. Because that is what i need.